# How to align solidworks global origin with assembly origin while exporting in solidworks to urdf

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, navigation, odometry, gazebo

I have created a robot model in solidworks and exported in solidworks to urdf plug-in. When exporting the co-ordinates of the model is misaligned which is causing problem while using in ROS.

[image]

As you could see in picture the Z-axis is horizontal in assembly whereas vertical in solidworks. How to align these co-ordinates. The generated co-ordinate system must be similar to solidworks' co-ordinates

PS: I have mated the assembly origin and base_link origin

Answer (score 5):

I did a little step-by-step tutorial with images, but if [my other answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/8869/9720) regarding aligning frames didn't work well for you, or the definition of "Front Plane" or "Top Plane" is confusing in Solidworks (spoiler: it is), then consider making your own axes.

From the assembly tab, go to reference geometry -> axis, then select the *assembly planes* to make an axis. There are three possible combinations of planes, giving you three unique axes (1-2, 1-3, 2-3).

Then, compare the axes to the global axes, and **rename them** to the same for clarity later.

Then, delete the old mates that are keeping the assembly grounded, then re-mate whatever lines you have that determine a particular frame to your newly-named axes you just made.

This should fix the problem for you.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]

Comment: Should i create line sketch in the base plate to align it with the created axis (To make the selection as shown in 5th image). I manually created a line sketch but i am getting "overdefine" error

Comment: While following the other answer i was able to create an URDF with correct co-ordinates. But when i launch and navigation stack in rviz and provide initial pose the robot appears in side ways Ref [Fig](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bf6ni9lqe8i5mtz/pose%20side.png?dl=0). My robot localization is poor, does this pose error has anything to do with localization.

Comment: @user3725099 - How are you setting the initial pose? Is it with a quaternion or Euler angles? Are you sure you're entering the initial pose correctly? What values are you using? With a 3D rotation matrix and Euler angles, order of rotation matters, and you won't get to the correct ending pose if you don't transform in the correct sequence. Without more information I can't really comment any more, but maybe this should be a [new question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Regarding the line sketch, I based my pictures on  your pictures; I thought you already had labeled axes in the base plate of [your drawing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xGkyg.png).

Comment: That was URDF reference angle created after executing preview in solidworks to URDF plug-in. Can't we use the default axis of the part, How to view and use the part axis in solidworks? Ref files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ny6l3qn3hadht6p/AABICpC5cgaefL6WNyuv1hPEa?dl=0)